# Change iTerm2 tab title dynamically for Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, iterm

I am using iTerm2 and usually have many tabs open. Unfortunately all tabs show me the same title "ruby" as it is all ruby scripts.

But one is rails server, the other rails console, the next is "spork", ... I would like to set the tab titles dynamically to "server", "console" or something similar as long as the processes are running and back to the default ("bash") when they are finished.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This command will set a tab's title to MY_NEW_TITLE

echo -e "\033];MY_NEW_TITLE\007"

Comment: I knew that, but the tab title doesn't change back to the default when a process finished.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this depends on your shell.

I use zsh, which allows you to define hook functions which are run when command are run, before the prompt is printed, etc (actually, the code I'm using lives on [github](https://github.com/mattfoster/zshkit/blob/master/10_hooks).

It looks as though bash has [similar functionality](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command).

I'd probably use the `echo` command in one of the other answers here, or zsh's title function to set the title from within your scripts, then ensure it's set back using a hook which runs before the next prompt is drawn.