# How does this script for naming iTerm tabs work?

Tags: bash, shell, iterm

I'm trying to name my iTerm tabs and found [this link.](http://blog.locut.us/2009/10/30/simple-bash-script-to-name-a-tab-in-iterm/) Here is the pertinent part of the guy's post:

> I wrote a simple script, which I call “nametab”, which allows you to name the tab you are in from the command line. You just type something like:
>
> ```
> $ nametab New tab name
> ```
>
> If you’d like to use this yourself, here is the code:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # A simple script which will name a tab in iTerm
> # usage:
> # $ nametab New tab name
>
> echo -ne "\033]0;"$@"\007"
> ```

I have created a directory `$HOME/dev/bash_scripts` and placed a file in that directory called `nametab.sh`.  I then switched to that directory and ran the command

```
chmod u+x nametab.sh
```

But when I try to name my current tab in iTerm by typing `nametab.sh New tab hellooooo`, nothing happens.  I also tried `nametab.sh hellooooo`, and nothing happens.

Can you help me understand what I don't understand?

---

### Update:

```
echo TERM=$TERM
```

returns

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

and

```
echo $PATH
```

returns

```
.:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:~/dev/bash_scripts
```

and

```
cat ~/dev/bash_scripts/nametab.sh
```

returns

```
#!/bin/bash

# A simple script which will name a tab in iTerm
# usage:
# $ nametab NewTabName

echo "trying to rename the current tab to $@"
echo -ne "\033]0;"$@"\007"
echo "finished"
```

and

```
nametab.sh hellooooo
```

returns

```
trying to rename the current tab to helloooo
finished
```

but the tab name always stays the same.

Incidentally, the tab name reads

```
MindRoot (bash)
```

I am running iTerm2.  I try to do all my bash shell configuration in `/etc/bashrc`.  This way I get the same bash terminal behavior regardless of which user account I am logged in on.  The contents of `/etc/bashrc` is

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

#PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

# ALL OF THE BELOW ADDED BY DEONOMO ON 2011-04-25

# custom prompt
PROMPT_HOSTNAME='MindRoot' 
PROMPT_COLOR='0;35m'

# If I am root, set the prompt to bright red
if [ ${UID} -eq 0 ]; then
PROMPT_COLOR='1;31m'
fi

PS1='\[\e]1;${PROMPT_HOSTNAME}\a\e]2;${PROMPT_HOSTNAME}:${PWD}\a\
\e[${PROMPT_COLOR}\]\
[\u@${PROMPT_HOSTNAME} \w]\n \#\$ \
\[\e[m\]'

#PS1="\e[0;45m\w:$ "

# added by Deonomo on 2011/09/12 in order to have textmate work as default editor
export EDITOR='mate -w'

# added by Deonomo on 2012-01-11 in order to start a dev/bash_scripts directory
export PATH="$PATH:~/dev/bash_scripts"
```

Comment: Can you try running the script as `./nametab.sh Hellooo`? Or add a line to script to make sure it has been run at all.

Comment: Evidently I can't put code in the comments box, *sigh*  Basically, I added the lines <code>echo "trying to rename the current tab"</code> and <code>echo "finished"</code> right before and after the line that reads <code>echo -ne "\033]0;"$@"\007"</code>.  Now when I run the script it just prints those two lines ("trying to rename the current tab" and then "finished"), but my tab name does not change.

Comment: I added the lines 'echo "trying to rename the current tab"' and 'echo "finished"' right before and after the line that reads 'echo -ne "\033]0;"$@"\007"'.  Now when I run the script it just prints those two lines ("trying to rename the current tab" and then "finished"), but my tab name does not change.

Comment: sheesh -- how can I get the grey-background code style to appear in these comment boxes??? 'test'

Comment: According to this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874404/change-iterm2-tab-title-dynamically-for-ruby-rails the command echo -e "\033];MY_NEW_TITLE\007" should change my tab name, but it is not doing so.  Could it be that something else I have set in a .bash_profile or .bashrc file is preventing the command from working?  Thanks.

Comment: To get code into a comment, use the backquote: `

Comment: Also, in the linked page, only `echo -e` is used, but you also specify `-n`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: rather than the original poster show code as comments, better for him to edit it question with the new facts. Also per 'it is not doing so', please edit your post to show what the output of `echo TERM=$TERM`.  Good luck to all.

Comment: thanks for helping.  I have edited my original post above.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have an alias for changing the tab name, you can actually do it by defining a function in your .profile/.bashrc file like this:

```
function renametab () {
    echo -ne "\033]0;"$@"\007"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having your same problem - but I saw the tab name briefly flash before going to back to what it was: the shell and the cwd. Turns out I had an environment variable changing the tab name on every shell command, so this fixed it for me:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=''
```

Now: echo -e "\033];MY_NEW_TITLE\007"

..works just fine and persists.

Comment: How can I turn this into an alias? This doesn't work for me in iterm2: alias tabname="echo -ne \"\033]0;"\$@"\007\""

Answer (score 0):

```
rename_tab () {
    TEXT=$1
    export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${TEXT}\007"'
}
```

This is a function. You can add it to your `~/.bashrc` (or something similar, like a `~/.bash_profile`). To rename the tabs, you can then do this:

`$ rename_tab 'NEW NAME HERE'`