# iTerm2 tab names change; what is this bash command?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, iterm2

I use iTerm2 as my terminal on OS X. When I SSH into a machine, I like to name my tabs by going into the session preferences (`cmd + i`). Whenever I run another bash command after setting this preference, the tab title goes back to the default that it was when I first SSHd in.

Browsing around for an answer, I [found this answer by Chad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823103/how-does-this-script-for-naming-iterm-tabs-work) that is working for me:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=''
echo -e "\033];MY_NEW_TITLE\007"
```

I don't really understand the `PROMPT_COMMAND` line, though I tried looking it up.

**Can someone explain this in simple terms?**

**Same question for the 2nd line, as I don't even know how to begin researching that.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [iTerm2 escape code](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html) .
I didn't read the related iTerm2 code thoroughly, but it seems like an interface to manipulate iTerm2.
I guess iTerm2 does this magic by  parse the output of screen if the contents fit special format(start by "\033]" and so on), iTerm2 will consider that's the information mean to sent to itself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know iTerm2 had proprietary escape codes; that's the piece I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: Upon further research, the escaping of those octal representations of ascii are not proprietary iTerm2 escape codes. They are just plain bash escape codes.

Comment: They are actually terminal escape codes; they are unrelated to Bash. Many are inherited all the way back from VT52/VT100 terminals but this one in particular was introduced in `xterm` (hardware terminals obviously did not have a window title).

Answer (score 1):

To keep the original tab:

Go to Iterm's Preferences > Profiles > Terminal

Uncheck **"Terminal may set tab/window title"**

Now you can name your tab, ssh into a server, exit and still keep the original tab name.

Credit to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/czV-sv4ykzI

Answer (score 0):

I used [tabset](https://github.com/jonathaneunice/iterm2-tab-set) node plugin. It works like a charm, and also color codes each tab, and has multiple options to color code, add a badge and even bring up a color picker to choose.